# How to use deep learning to train an AI to play a two-player tactic game like rock-papers-scissors?

Tags: deep-learning, game-ai

I want to try to train an AI model that can [play a simple two-player tactic game](http://www.wikibin.org/articles/bor-bor-zan-2.html). The game is not rock-papers-scissors, but have similar properties.

- Firstly, two players present their moves simultaniously, and it's not turn based. [So this artical discussing step-based games like tic-tac-toe doesn't help.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/build-an-ai-for-two-player-turn-based-games/) The minimax algorithm cannot work in this condition.
- Secondly, to each different play the computer faces, their should be a different winning tactic. **I would like to train the AI model to let it learn effectively to the opponent's tactics.** [Consider this article on rock-papers-scissors](http://www.datasmith.org/2020/05/17/ai-for-rock-paper-scissors/): At the beginning of the article, there is an interactive presentation of how the AI model performs. It seems that after winning the AI easily a few times, the AI seems to develop a good sense of predicting what move will the opponent come up next. I hope the AI trained on this game should behave like this too.

The biggest difference between this game and rock-papers-scissors is that there are no core stategies that the AI can follow, and the games does not end on the first round. So the AI needs to develop a stategy itself to face the opponent and maximize its chances of winning. How do I achieve this goal? I'm not an expert in machine learning or deep learning, so please make the explanation simple. I don't need much code, just guidance on how to program and train this AI.